# How to install pip in python 3.4 on windows?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4

I'm really struggling at installing any python modules (e.g six, yahoo_finance) because they require pip to be installed, but I don't know whether I have pip already or how to install it. Once its installed I don't know what command to type in and where to type it in. Can I install these modules any other way without pip?

I am only a beginner, so sorry if this is a bit basic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pip` comes already bundled with `python 3.4` It will be in your scripts directory `C:\Python34\Scripts\`
Add it to your `Environment variables` and you can run it from any directory or else open the directory mentioned above in command prompt and run `pip install ...` to install whatever you want

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helped - been searching around for ages

Comment: Dang! you beat me to it! :D

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have it installed, if not follow the instructions below. Type `which pip`, and if it doesn't list an URL, it means it's not installed yet.

Go here https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and download the file.

Then open terminal and go to your downloads folder (or wherever you downloaded it to) and type `python get-pip.py` to execute the script. If you get an error that says `OSError: Permission Denied`, or something similar, run it with administrator permissions.

If the installation is successful, you should now have pip installed on your computer. Type `pip --version` to make sure you have it installed.

To install six and yahoo_finance, type:

```
pip install six
```

and

```
pip install yahoo-finance
```

If something goes wrong update your question.

Answer (score 1):

From [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#key-terms):

> pip is the preferred installer program. Starting with Python 3.4, it is **included by default** with the Python binary installers.

Emphasis mine

If you already installed it by default you should be able to use it.
Just open the command line and type `python -m pip install SomePackage`.

Comment: @James What do you mean? Could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: /Users/User/.profile and /Users/User/.bash_profile. Its path t has to be there (or rather, best to be there) if the command is runnable. /where/ever/pip/is/bin has to be added if the tool's binary is in that folder.